# Audio sync, call function every 1 / 44.1 millisecond

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web-audio-api

In JavaScript, is it possible to call a function playing 10 different wav sounds at 44.1 kHz and call that same function again in (1/44100)*(128/60)*16 seconds with a 1/44.1 millisecond precision preferably with chrome/safari and in that case how?

I'm looking at making a music loop machine playing a few simultaneous loops. The precision is needed otherwise there will be unwanted hearable issues with the sounds (phasing).

Comment: Are you aware of requestAnimationFrame? http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Whatever you're trying to accomplish almost certainly calls for a different approach than the one you're suggesting.  Maybe if you tell us the problem you're trying to solve, we can tell you how to solve it, rather than proposing the solution and asking us to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Mark, havn't checked requestAnimationFrame yet - sounds familiar though. Robert, sure I will try to rephrase the question more general. thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robert,

It's possible to *measure* time with high accuracy - via performance.now() - but you cannot get a callback with that kind of precision.  In fact, in light of layout passes and JavaScript execution in the main thread, and the ever-looming threat of garbage collection happening in the main thread, you can't get anywhere NEAR even millisecond precision; you generally ought to be planning on potential interruptions in the tens of milliseconds for robustness.

The answer to this is to use scheduling, particularly in the Web Audio API - I see that you saw the article I wrote about this a year ago on HTML5Rocks (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/), but you missed the significant piece - you shouldn't be calling

```
audioSource2.noteOn(0, 0.1190, 1.875);
```

you need the *time* offset to schedule it ahead appropriately:

```
audioSource2.noteOn(time, 0.1190, 1.875);
```

If you look at my original code, that's how I'm scheduling the oscillator ahead of time.  The scheduler runs in a "slow" callback loop - being called only every 100ms or so - but schedules ahead a few beats.  If you truly need to mute notes that may already be scheduled in the next 1/10th of a second, then you can keep a node in the middle to disconnect().

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at either [DOM High Resolution timestamp](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#sec-DOMHighResTimeStamp), which can be accessed with `window.performance.now()`, or [request Animation Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame), with `window.requestAnimationFrame`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library which I have written : https://github.com/sebpiq/WAAClock

It lets you schedule things precisely and easily and also provides useful functionalities such as : cancel event, change tempo, ... everything necessary for a loop machine. Under the hood, it implements the tricks explained in this article (already linked by other people) : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

If by loop machine you mean continuously looping a few samples (and not a drum machine, where you just play a sample at a point in time), you might also want to look into this : https://github.com/sebpiq/WAATableNode